# How can I highlight searched words in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been looking around for a while but I can't seem to find a well received, robust method of achieving this.

Basically, when a user searches for something on my web page, say **ADDM**, then when the page reloads to show the search results, I want every entry containing the letters **ADDM** to be highlighted (or even just bold).

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130130/how-to-highlight-all-occurrences-of-a-word-on-a-page-with-javascript-or-jquery/32130293#32130293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are going to reload the page, which means that the view will be re-rendered, you could use the [`highlight`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/highlight) helper in your view to wrap the searched text in an HTML element. Then you can have specific styling for these elements. For example, given that you have a `search#show` action, you *store* the search text in a `search` key at your `params`, you could do it like this:

```
# app/views/search/show.html.haml
- @results.each do |result|
  .result
    = highlight result.description, params[:search]
```

The you could have some CSS in place for `mark` elements (generated by the helper) to style them as you please, for example:

```
mark {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #EFEFEF;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this approach does not require javascript at all.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by how you formatted the code in the view without the embedded Ruby notation, could you maybe edit what you have to make it a tiny bit clearer?

Comment: never mind, I got it, thanks for the help :D , a lot more elegant than using a bunch of JS